# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in JS (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have JS script to get data from back end

Here is script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    emaillist_update();
});

function emaillist_update() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Displayinfo", "Questions")',
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            ID: id
        }
        success: function(result) {
            var info = result;
            $("#vacancy").append("Мы ищем специалиста на вакансию:" + info.Vacancy);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

And here is code on back - end

```
 public ActionResult Displayinfo(int ID)
    {
        var res = db.Interview
            .Where(x => x.Interview_Id == ID)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Vacancy = x.Vacancy.VacancyName,
                Greeting = x.Greeting,
                Detail = x.Detail
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in this row `url: '@Url.Action("Displayinfo", "Questions")',`

In what is trouble? url seems to be correct

Thank's for help

Comment: Try to delete complete __line__ and retype it(don't copy-paste), may be there is some invisible character

Comment: nope, it is in view @Satpal

Comment: It's funny, but it's true@Satpal

Comment: Yes dude, it works@Satpal